# How to group data by Date and compare it by Month MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have huge CDR(call detail report) data like this :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54eecc9a6c6852b9f0575bbb"),
        "msisdn" : "9818895866",
        "callType" : "NA",
        "duration" : 13.5,
        "charges" : 200,
        "traffic" : "Data",
        "Date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T12:15:42.535Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54eecc9a6c6852b9f0575bbc"),
        "msisdn" : "9818356561",
        "callType" : "STD",
        "duration" : 20.100000381469727,
        "charges" : 100,
        "traffic" : "Voice",
        "Date" : ISODate("2014-01-09T00:11:14.646Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54eecc9a6c6852b9f0575bbd"),
        "msisdn" : "9818173670",
        "callType" : "NA",
        "duration" : 19.399999618530273,
        "charges" : 300,
        "traffic" : "Data",
        "Date" : ISODate("2014-01-13T19:48:47.789Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54eecc9a6c6852b9f0575bbe"),
        "msisdn" : "9818719936",
        "callType" : "Local",
        "duration" : 9,
        "charges" : 350,
        "traffic" : "SMS",
        "Date" : ISODate("2014-03-02T10:51:29.846Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54eecc9a6c6852b9f0575bbf"),
        "msisdn" : "9818612562",
        "callType" : "STD",
        "duration" : 5.110000133514404,
        "charges" : 450,
        "traffic" : "Voice",
        "Date" : ISODate("2014-01-08T16:41:30.327Z")
}
```

i want to display usage of TRAFFIC="DATA" Sum of Previous month duration > sum of current  month duration * 2

Display only sum of greater msisdn field

i tried this one

```
db.CDR.aggregate([ { $match : { traffic : "Data" }},{"$group" : {  
       "_id" : {  
            "Msisdn" : "$msisdn",  
            "Month" : "$date"  
       },  
       "Total Duration" : {  
            "$sum" : "$duration"  
       },  
       "Count" : {  
            "$sum" : 1  
       }  
  }  
 }])
```

It displays all time sum of duration.

I want to group by Month and compare each month and display only greater msisdn.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement more clearly? I don't understand what result you want based on your description or attempted pipeline. Can you include an example of what the output would ideally look like?

Comment: ok i want to compareall Msisdn field By Month. Previous month to current month.

Comment: if msisdn Data field usage is greater than previous month then it display record.
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54eecc9a6c6852b9f0575bbd"),
        "msisdn" : "9818173670",
        "callType" : "NA",
        "duration" : 19.399999618530273,
        "charges" : 300,
        "traffic" : "Data",
        "Date" : ISODate("2014-01-13T19:48:47.789Z")
}

in this document duration is usage of data.